# Playa - var_prefix question

Tags: playa

I'm having trouble getting var_prefix to work with the exp:playa:parents tag.

Here's my code:

```
                        {exp:channel:entries 
                        channel="skills"
                        orderby="title"
                        sort="asc"
                        category="65"
                        parse="inward"
                        disable="member_data|pagination|category_fields"
                    }
                        <p>{title}</p>
                        {exp:playa:parents 
                            channel="skills" 
                            entry_id="{entry_id}"
                            var_prefix="pre"
                        }
                        {if pre:total_results > 1}
                            {if pre:count == 1}
                            <a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#content-{entry_id}"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign"></span></a>
                            {/if}
                        {/if}
                        {/exp:playa:parents}

                    {/exp:channel:entries}
```

I'm trying to achieve two things:

1. I would like to get the total_results and count variables for the results from the playa tag and not the parent exp:channel:entries tag.
2. I would like to get the exp:channel:entries {entry_id} inserted in this line data-target="#content-{entry_id}" rather than the {entry_id} from the exp:playa:parent entry.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try removing the `parse="inward"` parameter from your `{exp:channel:entries}` tag. It may be confusing things and you don't really need it anyway.

Comment: Hi kgrote, I tried removing the parse parameter but that wasn't the problem. I realized that I am able to get a value for pre:count but the problem is I can't use it in a conditional. Is this a limitation of the using var_prefix or a bug?

Comment: Try writing it this way: `{if '{pre:count}' == '1'}`.

Comment: That did the trick, thanks your a life saver.